# PHP Parse URL-encoded string with embedded JSON

Tags: php, json, parse-url

I am having a problem parsing the following xAPI string into an array. The issue is that both parse_str() and parse_url() parse the URL within the quotes contained in the [content] ... which kills the JSON format.

```
Authorization=Basic YmV0b1234XZlddle9ighrXRvc3VhdmVwY999929yZA==&Content-Type=application/json&X-Experience-API-Version=1.0.0&statementId=ef0ca1d6-1234-4e02-b403-7d4aab0df62c&content={"verb":{"id":"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/experienced"},"object":{"id":"http://mytest.myfavsite.com/?post_type=gb_xapi_content&amp;p=52&amp;preview=true/6lgIX5Hxep0","definition":{"name":{"und":"SpecificStatement"},"description":{"und":"SpecificStatement"},"type":"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/module"},"objectType":"Activity"},"context":{"contextActivities":{"grouping":{"id":"http://mytest.myfavsite.com/?post_type=gb_xapi_content&amp;p=52&amp;preview=true"},"parent":{"id":"http://mytest.myfavsite.com/?post_type=gb_xapi_content&amp;p=52&amp;preview=true"}},"registration":"36fc1ee0-2849-1234-b697-71cd4cad1b6e"},"version":"1.0.0","actor":{"mbox":"mailto:betosuave@home.tld","name":"beto","objectType":"Agent"}}
```

What I would like to wind-up with is an array of element with an intact JSON string in the [content] array element.

Is there a method of parsing the string like parse_str() does ... while ignoring anything inside the quotes of the JSON element - e.g.,  `{"id":"http://mytest.myfavsite.com/?post_type=gb_xapi_content&amp;p=52&amp;preview=true"}`

Thank you in-advance for any ideas.

Comment: instead of getting it thru a url, do you have another way of getting that data? like `POST` instead?

Comment: @Beto Please note that the string you provide is not a URL. Are you sure it is correct? Then, if is possible, follow the Ghost idea. I have not found nothing best of my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `json_decode($string)` first and then run `parse_str()` on selected element.

Answer (score 0):

The question is interesting.

While will search for a clean solution, you can certainly try in the rude, old-fashioned way:

```
json_decode( substr( $str, strpos( $yourString, '&content=' )+9 ) )
```

This works fine!